# Not able to run power shell script in.Net console app using System.automation.management(Power shell package)

Tags: c#, powershell

Hi I am creating an software where it should loggOff all except currently logged in user in Windows 10 system.
I am able loggoff using a powershell command in powershell. find command below:

```
quser | Select-String "Disc" | ForEach{logoff ($_.toString() -split ' +')[2]}
```

The above command perfectly works with powershell console.

When add it into my code c# and invoke the command its not working. Please find the code below.

```
string logOff = "quser | Select-String \"Disc\" | ForEach{logoff ($_.toString() -split ' +')[2]}";
PowerShell psExec = PowerShell.Create();
psExec.AddScript(logoff);
Collection<PSObject> results;
results = psExec.Invoke();
```

I have also tried by spawning child process of power shell. Please check code below:

```
 processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
 {
  UseShellExecute = false,
  FileName = "powershell.exe",
  Arguments = "quser | Select-String \"Disc\" | ForEach{logoff ($_.toString() -split ' +')[2]}"
 }
 Console.WriteLine("Starting child process...");
 using (var process = Process.Start(processInfo))
  {
   process.WaitForExit();
  }
```

I have also tried as below:

```
            using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps.AddScript("‪C:\\Users\\vijay.rm\\Desktop\\test.ps1");

                Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = ps.Invoke();

                foreach (PSObject item in PSOutput)
                {
                    if (item == null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item.BaseObject.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("Done");
                    }
                }
            }
```

where test.ps1 script contains:

```
quser | Select-String \"Disc\" | ForEach{logoff ($_.toString() -split ' +')[2]}
```

I have also checked with build by changing it to x86 and x64 but the result is same.

I didn't get any exceptions.

But also i didn't get users logged off.

I have also tried console app with adminstrative privilages.

I am expecting that when run c# code, all users except user who is logged in the computer should loggoff.
In order to check weather an user is logged Off or not, run below command in powershell:

```
Get-WMIObject -class Win32_UserProfile
```

You will get results something like this below:

```
__GENUS                          : 2
__CLASS                          : Win32_UserProfile
__SUPERCLASS                     :
__DYNASTY                        : Win32_UserProfile
__RELPATH                        : Win32_UserProfile.SID="S-1-5-21-329068152-1454471165-1417001333-8355646"
__PROPERTY_COUNT                 : 29
__DERIVATION                     : {}
__SERVER                         : BDC3-LX-G5N6QQ2
__NAMESPACE                      : root\cimv2
__PATH                           : \\BDC3-LX-G5N6QQ2\root\cimv2:Win32_UserProfile.SID="S-1-5-21-329068152-1454471165-14
                                   17001333-8355646"
AppDataRoaming                   : System.Management.ManagementBaseObject
Contacts                         : System.Management.ManagementBaseObject
Desktop                          : System.Management.ManagementBaseObject
Documents                        : System.Management.ManagementBaseObject
Downloads                        : System.Management.ManagementBaseObject
Favorites                        : System.Management.ManagementBaseObject
HealthStatus                     : 3
LastAttemptedProfileDownloadTime :
LastAttemptedProfileUploadTime   :
LastBackgroundRegistryUploadTime :
LastDownloadTime                 :
LastUploadTime                   :
LastUseTime                      : 20190917044128.412000+000
Links                            : System.Management.ManagementBaseObject
Loaded                           : True
LocalPath                        : C:\Users\vijay.rm
Music                            : System.Management.ManagementBaseObject
Pictures                         : System.Management.ManagementBaseObject
RefCount                         :
RoamingConfigured                : False
RoamingPath                      :
RoamingPreference                :
SavedGames                       : System.Management.ManagementBaseObject
Searches                         : System.Management.ManagementBaseObject
SID                              : S-1-5-21-329068152-1454471165-1417001333-8355646
Special                          : False
StartMenu                        : System.Management.ManagementBaseObject
Status                           : 0
Videos                           : System.Management.ManagementBaseObject
PSComputerName                   : BDC3-LX-G5N6QQ2
```

In  that loaded property should be false when we run the script or code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What most likely fails are the calls to the *external programs*, `quser.exe` and `logoff.exe` (likely the latter - I strongly suspect you need to run administrative privileges to log off other users' sessions).

The **stderr messages that external programs output show up in PowerShell's error stream, but they do not cause an *exception***, so your code runs and *fails quietly*.
(Similarly, an external program reporting a *nonzero exit code* does *not* cause PowerShell to take any action.)

To see what went wrong, **you must inspect `psExec.Streams.Error`**, i.e. the error messages collected during the call.

---

In a comment you state that on examining the error stream you found that the error message there complained about `quser` not being found as a command (`The term 'quser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. ...`).

This suggests one of two possible causes (it turned out to be (a)):

- Either (a): Your System32 folder (typically, `C:\Windows\System32`) is inexplicably not listed in your `Path` environment variable (`$env:Path`), which would be highly unusual, though, and is worth investigating further.

  - As a workaround in the meantime: while you could try to reference `quser.exe` and `logoff.exe` by their full paths, it gives you more flexibility to add the System32 folder to the `$env:PATH` as the first command.

```
string logOff = "$env:PATH += \";$env:windir\\System32\"; quser.exe | Select-String \"Disc\" | ForEach{logoff.exe ($_.toString() -split ' +')[2]}";
```

- Or (b): Your C# code uses the *32-bit* version of the PowerShell SDK, and in the distinct directory that 32-bit applications see as `C:\Windows\System32` (which in reality is `C:\Windows\SysWow64`), neither `quser.exe` nor `logoff.exe` exist.

  - You can try to call the *64-bit* versions, by explicitly referencing them via virtual directory `C:\Windows\SysNative`<sup>[1]</sup> (which is visible only to 32-bit applications):

```
string logOff = "C:\\Windows\\SysNative\\quser.exe | Select-String \"Disc\" | ForEach{C:\\Windows\\SysNative\\logoff.exe ($_.toString() -split ' +')[2]}";
```

---

<sup>[1] Note: I'm assuming that the root of your Windows installation is `C:\Windows`; a way to refer to it reliably even if it is located in a differently named directory is to use `$env:windir` instead of literal `C:\Windows`.</sup>

Comment: @Vjay: That your System32 folder is not in `$env:Path` is quite unusual, so it's worth looking into that. In the meantime, rather than using full paths, I suggest extending `$env:PATH` at the start of your command - please see my update. Also, allow me to give you the standard advice to newcomers in the following comment.